# php global variables

Tags: php, methods, class, global

I have a global variable $config, now i have a class and i want to use a value from config as a default argument for a class method like function f(var=$config['val']){} will this assignment work?

Comment: add some more detail , statement above are not clear.

Answer (score 6):

> will this assignment work?

No, it won't.

There is no way to do this automatically in the function definition.

You would have to define an empty default:

```
function f($var = null) {  .... }
```

and then fill `$var` with a value from your configuration array inside the method if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

No. What I would do is to add $config as an field to the class, like this:

```
class MyAwesomeClass {
  public $config;

  public function f() {
    ...
  }
}

$cls = new MyAwesomeClass;
$cls->config = $GLOBALS['config'];
$cls->f();
```